# Realizando UPDATE no ORACLE utilizando FROM

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Como fazer `UPDATE` em registros do Oracle sem utilizar uma cláusula `IN` para alterar dados em massa?

Dessa forma:

```
UPDATE TABELA1 SET DADO = DADO
  FROM TABELA2 
 WHERE TABELA1.CODIGO = TABELA2.CODIGO;
```

Atualmente ele me *força* a informar uma cláusula `IN`:

```
UPDATE TABELA1 SET DADO = DADO
 WHERE CODIGO IN (SELECT CODIGO FROM TABELA2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cláusula FROM não é aceita no comando UPDATE, por isso do uso da cláusula IN no WHERE. Aparentemente, ela é aceita em alguns Sistemas Gerenciadores de Banco de Dados como o Postgre. Mas se analisarmos o padrão ANSI, ele não vai estar presente. Fiz essa verificação no "ANSI SQL 99 Part 2 - SQL Foundation".